# AWS & Swift - AWS pod show strange errors with build fail (images attached)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

I have an old Objective-C project with AWS pod installed and everything is working fine.
Now, i have a new Swift project and i want to use the same AWS pod in it.
but when in install the pod, i cannot build because it shows a strange errors that i cannot change (because it in the AWS framework).

error code example:

```
#define AWSTMDiskCacheError(error) if (error) { NSLog(@"%@ (%d) ERROR: %@", \
                                    [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], \
                                    __LINE__, [error localizedDescription]); }
```

I installed in the beginning `pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.3.3'`, and after that i saw the errors, i removed the `'~> 2.3.3'` to get the latest version with `pod update` but i got the same errors.
i also tried to hard clean the project & remove the derived data.

images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code images - post the actual text. People are more likely to help you if they can copy and paste the text.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Podfile?

Comment: What version of XCode and iOS are you using? Can you use the latest SDK version: 2.6.11?

Comment: @Karthikeyan, i'm using Xcode 9.2. and I didn't limit the version of AWS's pod, so it should download automatically the last version right?

Comment: Your pod syntax for version will be downloading the 2.3.x latest. Can you try 2.6.x instead? pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.6.11' ?